# Proof intersection of finite collection $G$ is open set

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Suppose $G$=$\cap_{i=1}^{k}$ $G_{i}$ is open

Then $G$= $\cap_{i=1}^{k+1}$ $G_{i}$ = $\cap_{i=1}^{k}$ $G_{i}$ $\cap$ $G_{k+1}$

Solution:
Suppose that $G_{i}$ and $G_{k+1}$ are open sets

```
       $G$ = $G_{i}$ $\cap$ $G_{k+1}$
```

We want to proof that $G$ is open ? 
Let $x\in G$
$x \subseteq G_{i}$ $\cap$ $G_{k+1} $ 
$x\in G_{i}$   and   $x\in G_{k+1}$ 
Since $x\in G_{i}$ and $G_{k+1}$ is open set 
Then exist $v_{1}$ of $x$ s.t  $$v_{1} \subseteq G_{i}$$ 
Since $$x\in G_{i}$$ and $G_{k+1}$ is open 
Then exist $v_{2}$ of $x$ s.t $$v_{2} \subseteq G_{k+1} $$
Therefore  $$x\in v_{1} \land v_{2}$$
and $v_{1}$ $\land$ $v_{2}$ is nbhd of $x$ 
$G_{i}$ $\cap$ $G_{k+1}$ is open set 
$G$ is open set . 
This proof true?

Comment: Thank you *so* much for properly using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)! If your union is not a binary operator as in $A\cup B$, it is better to replace it with `\bigcup` as in $$\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B_i$$

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is incoherent, but I think you mean the right thing. (It's very hard to tell.) I'll rephrase your proof according to what I think you were thinking as you wrote it.

---

We proceed by induction. Suppose that for any collection $G_1, \dots, G_k$ of $k$ open sets, the intersection $G := \cap_{i=1}^k G_i$ is open.

Then consider $\cap_{i=1}^{k+1} H_i$ for some open sets $H_i$. Write $H$ for that intersection, and write $G$ for the intersection of the first $k$ sets: $G := \cap_{i=1}^k H_i$. By inductive hypothesis, $G$ is open.

Let $x \in H$; we find an open neighbourhood of $x$ in $H$. Since $x \in G$, and $G$ is open, there is an open neighbourhood $v_1$ of $x$ in $G$; and since $x \in H_{k+1}$, there is an open neighbourhood $v_2$ of $x$ in $H_{k+1}$. So our open neighbourhood is $v_1 \cap v_2 \subseteq H$.

---

This works if you know that the intersection of two open sets is open, since you're missing the base case if you don't know that. This may be true by definition (if you're working in the setting of topological spaces) or you may have to prove it separately.